# is this right way for use cloud firestore document reference field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First, i create collection '**dnf**'.

I want manage reward item info using '**reward_item**' collection.

collection '**dnf**' structure below:

[image]

see '**list**' field, field '**id**' is reference type.

and collection '**reward_item**' below:

[image]

i expected get '**dnf.dungeon.list[0].detail.reward_item.id**' will return whole object of '**reward_item.5b0ec171...**'.

it is correct?